# Catch SocketTimeOutException In cxf Jaxrsclient

Tags: java, exception, webservice-client, socketexception, cxf-client

I am making a rest call using apache cxf . I am able to set timeout during invoking a service and corresponding socketConnection timeout exception gets thrown but i am not able to catch the exception and set it as user definied exception.  Please find the below code for time out exception

```
try{
    HTTPClientPolicy clientConfig = WebClient.getConfig(service).getHttpConduit().getClient(); clientConfig.setReceiveTimeout(10000);} 
catch(SocketTimeOutException e) {
          logger.error("");
         CustomException....
    }
```

Exception gets thrown without going inside catch block. Could someone tell me how can i catch this exception?

Comment: Add another catch statement `catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }` and you will know what exception is being thrown.

Comment: I looked at my console and it was SocketTimeOutException

Answer (score 0):

try to write

```
catch(Exception e) {
      logger.error("");
     CustomException....
}
```

instead of your code. Then you can catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: I tried catching it as you mentioned but not working.

Comment: the problem could be in the http connection not in your code

Comment: I am making a mock service n hitting it by myself and i am able to receive response . Timeout is even working. Only issue is how can i catch the timeout